# Why do some properties within my nested selectors in my scss file work while others are omitted?

Tags: html, css, sass

Specifically, I'm trying to style my anchor tags within my nav bar but it seems that only some styles work! The anchor tags are nested in my list-item tags, which are both nested in my `.navbar-nav` class.

For instance, in my `_nav.scss` file, I can alter the height of the nested anchor tags (increasing the height of the anchor's "active" background), which is what I need. However, when I try to specify the anchor's color or padding, I am unable to do so. What baffles me is that both of these properties/values can be successfully altered by entering them in the `style` attribute within the `<a>` tags.

As an example, I have specified these properties in my `home` anchor tag within my html file. I've entered the same property/values for the anchor tags within my scss file. The only anchor successfully altered is my `home` anchor tag. Any idea why?

```
<header class="header-main">
    <div id="top-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" 
     style="font-size: 30px;width: 100%;border: 1px solid red;">
      <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid green;width: 100%; 
       height:65px;" >
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a id="navbar-brand" class="navbar-brand" href="#" >Skyapp</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="active"><a href="index.html" style="padding-top:20px; color:purple;">Home</a></li>
            <-- Where I entered style attribute and values -->

            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

On to `my _nav.scss` file

```
#navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height:60px;
}

.navbar-nav{
    li{

        a{
            height:62px;
            color:blue;
            padding-top:20px;
            color:purple;
        }
    }
}

#navbar-brand{
    font-size: 35px;
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
}
```

Comment: If there are more than one css files, then some styles might be overwritten  by other files.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just ended up using "!important" to override my other css files.